# I wanted to do some automation in IE7. Could you help me to give path to download IEdriverServer for IE7

Tags: selenium

I wanted to do some automation in IE7. Could you help me to give path to download IEdriverServer for IE7. I tried using below link:
https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

But couldn't execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

I download IE server 2.46 lower to use on the IE7. 
Use that link https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
That should be resolved your problem

Comment: Thank you Tomash, let me try it.

Comment: Hi Tomash, Now I'm able to execute the script but when I check the version, it is showing IE 11. Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: @Rose what version of the IE you have in the machine? You need to have IE7 on your machine. If you have the latest Windows try to download a virtual machine and set up earlier Windows with IE7 on that and try to launch your scripts.

Comment: Thank you Tomash for the suggestion, let me try it.

Comment: U welcome if need more help.
Please feel free to ask